# Pandas change values in a groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I've a df like

```
   a   flag
0  1  False
1  0  False
2  1  False
3  0  False
4  0  False
```

and lets say I want to randomly put some `True` on every group in column `a` in order to obtain

```
   a   flag
0  1   True
1  0   True
2  1   True
3  0  False
4  0   True
```

So far I'm able to do so with the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def rndm_flag(ds, n):
    l = len(ds)
    n = min([l, n])
    vec = ds.sample(n).index
    ds["flag"] = np.where(ds.index.isin(vec),
                         True, ds["flag"])
    return(ds)

N = 5
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":np.random.randint(0,2,N),
                   "flag":[False]*N})

dfs = list(df.groupby("a"))
dfs = [x[1] for x in dfs]
df = pd.concat([rndm_flag(x, 2) for x in dfs])
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

But I'm wondering if there is an alternative (more elegant) way to do so.

Comment: df.groupby(level=0).a.transform(lambda x : np.random.randint(0, 2, 1)).astype(bool)

Comment: @Wen this doesn't do the trick. I was forcing to have at least two `True` per group. Plus I was looking for something where I can plug my custom (eventually more complex) function.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you some idea:

```
## create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,0,1,0,0], 'b':False})

## create flag
d['b'] = d.groupby('a').transform(lambda x: (np.random.choice([True, False], len(x), p = [0.65,0.35])))
print(d)

   a      b
0  1  False
1  0   True
2  1  False
3  0   True
4  0   True
```